# How to filter array that include object with an array data?

Tags: javascript

Here is my data:

```
const sectionDummy = [
  { floor: '1', data: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  { floor: '2', data: ['D', 'E', 'F']},
  { floor: '3', data: ['G', 'H', 'I']},
];
```

I can filter floor and get the correct data:

```
let filterData = [];
filterData = sectionDummy.filter(item => {
  if (item.floor !== undefined) {
    return item.floor.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) >= 0; 
  }
  return {};
});
```

If `inputValue` is 1, I will get the return data

```
console.log(filterData); // [{ floor: 1, data: ['A', 'B', 'C']}]
```

I'm stuck with the data array if I want to filter it too.

I try to use map

```
let filterData = [];
filterData = sectionDummy.filter(item => {
  if (item.floor !== undefined) {
    item.data.map((value, index) => {
      if(value.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) >=0) {
        return value;
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    });
  }
  return {};
});
```

It looks like filter and map data return is different, so it is not working.

How to filter both of `floor` and `data array` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `item.floor` looks to be an *integer*, so calling `.trim()` on it will throw an error..? (or is `sectionDummy` different from `searchBuildings`)

Comment: Why are you not using `sectionDummy.filter(item => item.floor === 1)` ?

Comment: .filter expects a boolean as the return value of the callback

Comment: the reason you return `{}` is because?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with proper inputs, expected output and a clear problem statement. Not `dummy` data

Comment: Please give input and output

Comment: @CertainPerformance It is String, I update the data on my question now.

Comment: is the `inputValue` same for both floor and data filtering?

Comment: @HassanImam It is a good suggestion. Thanks for your reply. I wonder to figure out how to filter my data array.

Comment: @vahdet Yes, I hope so.

Comment: @YongQuan Because when compare is nothing, I want to get an empty object.

Comment: What is the output when `A` is searched? Do you want the entire `data` array of `floor: 1` returned or just `A` inside the `data` array?

Comment: To filter your data array, you can use `array#some` or `array#includes`.

Comment: Thank you all. I get the answer from @Nina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to filter by the floor and then the data?

```js
const sectionDummy = [
  { floor: 1, data: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  { floor: 2, data: ['D', 'E', 'F']},
  { floor: 3, data: ['G', 'H', 'I']},
];

const floorFilter = 2;
const dataFilter = 'E';

const filteredData = sectionDummy
  .filter(item => item.floor === floorFilter)
  .map(({floor, data}) => ({floor, data: data.filter(d => d === dataFilter)}));
  
console.log(filteredData); //[ { floor: 2, data: [ 'E' ] } ]
```

Or by the floor and by the data?

```js
const sectionDummy = [
  { floor: 1, data: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  { floor: 2, data: ['D', 'E', 'F']},
  { floor: 3, data: ['G', 'H', 'I']},
];

const floorFilter = 2;
const dataFilter = 'E';

const filteredData = sectionDummy
  .filter(({floor, data}) => floor === floorFilter && data.some(d => d === dataFilter))
  
console.log(filteredData) // [ { floor: 2, data: [ 'D', 'E', 'F' ] } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that is very clear. I want to filter by the floor and the data. It user type `D` I still can get `[ { floor: 2, data: [ 'D', 'E', 'F' ] } ]`, so I change && with ||, but I get an empty object. Can you give me some suggestion ? Thanks you.

Comment: Does it mean, only one filter can be set?

Comment: With `.filter(({floor, data}) => floor === floorFilter || data.some(d => d === dataFilter))` and `const floorFilter = undefined` it actually works...

Comment: Yes, It works now. Because my data array is not A B C, it is like ['Mcdonalds', 'StarBuckts'], I have to try to compare all of the string. Thanks you very much @ttulka !

Comment: If you has the time can you give me some suggestion. If I just type M then I can compare the Mcdonalds in my condition. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `.filter(({floor, data}) => floor === filter || data.some(d => d === filter || String(d).charAt(0) === filter))`

Comment: I get the idea. Learn a lots from your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this: If the `searchText` matches `floor`, then return the entire `section`. Else if the `searchText` exists in `data`, then return a section object with filtered `data` array.

```js
const sectionDummy = [
  { floor: "1", data: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  { floor: "2", data: ['D', 'E', 'F']},
  { floor: "3", data: ['G', 'H', 'I']},
];

const filter = (sections, searchText) => {
  searchText = searchText.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  return sections.reduce((acc, { floor, data }) => {
    if (floor === searchText) {
      acc.push({ floor, data })
    } else {
      const filtered = data.filter(d => d.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
      if (filtered.length > 0)
        acc.push({ floor, data: filtered })
    }

    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(filter(sectionDummy, "A"))
console.log(filter(sectionDummy, "G"))
console.log(filter(sectionDummy, "1"))
```

Comment: Thank you again. Your answer helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by checking `floor` and `inputValue` and take the objects it the two values are equal.

```
let filterData = searchBuildings.filter(({ floor }) => floor === inputValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to filter both of floor and data array actually.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.